# Is the use of the word "irony" correct in this paragraph?

Tags: grammar, irony

I recently came across a Facebook post, about a city in India known as Patiala. I was arguing with the admin, about the correct usage of the word irony. Is the word correctly used in the following paragraph? If yes, what kind of irony is it?

> Congratulation to Patiala as Royal City turns 250 year Older on
>   12-2-2013.
>
> It is an irony that Patiala will enter its 250th anniversary all
>   alone, with none to throw a party and none to congratulate it for the
>   feat that it is poised it achieved on Tuesday. It is an irony that
>   nobody remembers the ‘birthday’ of one of the most amiable cities of
>   Punjab. Neither the district administration nor any other organisation
>   has planned any celebrations to commemorate the historical feat.

Comment: I'm afraid this text has other problems besides the word *irony*, such as several grammatical mistakes.

Comment: @Cerberus Yea, I noticed those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not dramatic irony, which relates solely to fictional, dramatic contexts.  Your true story reflects [situational irony](http://grammar.about.com/od/tz/g/situationalironyterm.htm), which is the irony of a situation whose outcome is contrary to what was expected.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be correct, in saying that despite the city's historical achievements, at the same time, that no one will remember or celebrate it. Why have a significant anniversary like a 250th without a celebration?

Comment: Can you tell me what kind of irony is it. Apparently there are 7 kinds: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Irony

Comment: Those are not different kinds of irony, they all describe what it is NOT.

Answer (score -1):

I think this might be dramatic irony.

Comment: That's great. Can you explain why?